# How can I convert the response of a http.MultipartRequest POST method in a map<String, dynamic> in Flutter?

Tags: http, flutter, mobile, flutter-test

I am using the following approach:

```
 var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(urlAdicionaItem));
 request.fields["comanda"] = numeroComanda.toString();
 request.fields["produto"] = idProduto.toString();
 request.fields["quantidade"] = quantidade.toString();

 var res = await request.send();
```

But I don't know how to convert res.stream in the response.body to process data like using a regular http.post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example `res` will be a [StreamedResponse](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/StreamedResponse-class.html) which can be turned into a `String` like this:

```
final responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
```